# How to set up Nginx correctly when 403 Forbidden on CentOS 7?

Tags: nginx, centos7

On CentOS 7

`/etc/hosts`:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6

192.168.0.1  app1
```

Installed Nginx from package:

```
yum install nginx
```

In `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`:

```
# ...
include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

server {
    listen       80 default_server;
    listen       [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name  _;
    root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

    # Load configuration files for the default server block.
    include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

    location / {
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;
        location = /40x.html {
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
    }
}
# ...
```

Created a new file under `/etc/nginx/sites-available/` named `myapp`:

```
upstream app {
    # Path to Unicorn SOCK file, as defined previously
    server unix:///home/deploy/myapp/tmp/sockets/unicorn.sock;
}

server {
    listen 192.168.0.1:80;
    server_name app1;

    # Application root, as defined previously
    root /home/deploy/myapp/public;

    try_files $uri/index.html $uri @app;

    location @app {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass http://app;
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
    client_max_body_size 4G;
    keepalive_timeout 10;
}
```

Link it to `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/`:

```
cd /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/
ln -s ../sites-available/myapp
```

Restart nginx:

```
service nginx restart
```

Then try to access url:

```
curl 192.168.0.1
```

Got error:

```
<html>
<head><title>403 Forbidden</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>403 Forbidden</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.10.2</center>
</body>
</html>
```

I removed default `index.html` file under `/usr/share/nginx/html` path, so it got 403 Forbidden.

Nginx error log `/var/log/nginx/error.log`:

```
2017/07/25 03:35:59 [error] 8200#0: *1 directory index of "/usr/share/nginx/html/" is forbidden, client: 192.168.0.2, server: _, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "192.168.0.1"
```

Why it accessed default `/usr/share/nginx/html/` path, but not new added `myapp` under `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/` directory?

Comment: use a different port and try again

Comment: Is the default conf still in the sites-enabled dir? You probably didn't disable the default site and enable your myapp site.

Comment: @Chase No, both the `sites-available` and `sites-enabled` folder have just one file named `myapp`. There isn't `default` in it.

Comment: both virtual servers are listening to the same **ip:port** pair and the the first one is marked as the default server.
When you request `192.168.0.1` Nginx match the **Host** header against the `server_name` but None of them matches, so it is routed to the default server.

Comment: @mononoke I added `192.168.0.1 app1` to `/etc/hosts` file. So I think the `server_name` in config file is right. Even I changed that to `localhost`, got the same result.

Comment: @cloud_cloud how do you access your server after you modify hosts file, by ip or server name?

Comment: @mononoke Both by IP and server name all failed: `curl 192.168.0.1`. `curl app1`. From error.log can see it also accessed the `/usr/share/nginx/html` path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real problem is, the OS distribution version and package version, makes software different.

> Attention: It's CentOS 7.3!

The method I used to install nginx was:

```
yum update
yum install epel-release
yum install nginx
```

Then, the nginx version maybe a little different from others like package on Ubuntu. So the usage is not the same, too.

Its directory is:

```
/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
/etc/nginx/conf.d/
# Notice, there aren't these directories exist!
/etc/nginx/sites-available/
/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/
```

So the usage is different and the following is necessary!

First, comment out the default setting in `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`:

```
#    server {
#        listen       80 default_server;
#        listen       [::]:80 default_server;
#        server_name  _;
#        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;
#
#        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
#        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;
#
#        location / {
#        }
#
#        error_page 404 /404.html;
#            location = /40x.html {
#        }
#
#        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
#            location = /50x.html {
#        }
#   }
```

Second, create the new config for application under `/etc/nginx/conf.d/`:

```
# File Name: rails.conf
upstream app {
    # Path to Unicorn SOCK file, as defined previously
    server unix:/home/deploy/myapp/tmp/sockets/unicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    listen 192.168.0.1:80;
    server_name app1;

    # Application root, as defined previously
    root /home/deploy/myapp/public;

    try_files $uri/index.html $uri @app;

    location @app {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header X-FORWARDED_PROTO https;
        proxy_pass http://app;
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
    client_max_body_size 4G;
    keepalive_timeout 10;
  }
```

If exist `default.conf` under `/etc/nginx/conf.d/`, remove it.

Third, check syntax and restart nginx:

```
nginx -t
service nginx restart
```

It will access the path pointed to `/home/deploy/myapp/public` when run `curl 192.168.0.1`.

Answer (score 0):

The error your getting is saying that nginx is not able to access the index folder of /usr/share/nginx/html/ this is happening when it hot the tryfile @app directive in the app.conf.the reason for that is that by default nginx have autoindex off; that mean if you request a / path it will not allowed on a try_file.
see:
[autoindex](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_autoindex_module.html)

in your case you need to add autoindex on; directive in the server before the try_file directive.

Comment: Thank you. Could you tell me where should add `autoindex on;`? In `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` or `/etc/nginx/sites-available/myapp` ? I tried to add it in `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`, but when access it got `Index of /`.

Comment: It's also went to access default `/usr/share/nginx/html` path.

Comment: you need to add it to app not the default, it's the one that have the try_file and got hit by your request. Try to add it in the server block before the try_file in the myapp config file